# Create email survey with MailJet

Tags: survey, mailjet

I would like to create email campaign with MailJet. A would like to ask recipients:

"Will you come to party?"

A would like to provide to buttons/links (*Yes* and *No*), so that recipient can click his decision. I would later like to see results of my survey in my mailJet account.

Both link (*Yes* and *No*) should target somewhere to mailJet (I don't want to create special app hosted on my domain... I would like mailJet to do everything).

Is that possible in MailJet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are currently beta testing possible solution which may be suitable for you. Please reach out to our [support](https://www.mailjet.com/support/ticket), selecting the API category and mentioning this post for details.